# Reactjs passing methods as props to child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a way to pass methods of current class to child class as props

As an example;

```
var SignupModal = React.createClass({
mixins: [CheckMixin],
getInitialState: function(){
  return {
      'wizardstate': 0
  }
},
setWizardState: function(state){
    var that = this;
    switch (state){
        case 0:
           that.setState({'wizardstate': 0});
           break;
        case 1:
            that.setState({'wizardstate': 1});
            break;
        case 2:
            that.setState({'wizardstate': 2});
            break;
        case 3:
            that.setState({'wizardstate': 3});
            break;
        case 4:
            that.setState({'wizardstate': 4});
            break;
    }
},
render: function(){
    var temp;
    switch (this.state.wizardstate){
        case 0:
           temp = (<SignupSetup setWizardState={this.setWizardState}/>);
            break;
        case 1:
            temp = (<EmailSetup />);
            break;
        case 2:
            temp = (<PasswordSetup />);
            break;
        case 3:
            temp =  (<UsernameSetup />);
            break;
        case 4:
            temp = (<CategoriesSetup />);
            break;
    }
    return (<Modal {...this.props} title="Login" animation={false}>
            <div className="modal-body">
                <div>
                {temp}
                </div>
            </div>
        </Modal>)


var SignupSetup = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (<Button onClick={this.props.setWizardState(1)}></Button>)
    }
});
```

I want to pass this setWizardState method of SignupModal to child SignupSetup as prop, but i get the error

`Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: replaceState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within`render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.react.js:17122`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problems are here:

```
<Button onclick={this.props.setWizardState(1)}></Button>
```

First is a typo (`onClick`, capital **C**).  But the main problem is that you're calling `setWizardState`, and onClick takes a function.  You need to partially apply it.

```
onClick={this.props.setWizardState.bind(null, 1)}
```

Comment: Antony, they want the number to be the first argument to the function, but not call the function in render.  There are various reasons people have trouble understanding this, so could you explain where you're confused?

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand Please give me detail explanation about this issues, i have stucked in this issue for long time after i applied as you mentioned above. Everything is fit and fine. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @SusylGhimire I don't know what else to say

Comment: then how you know that you should pass null parameter and bind this method which eventually solves the problem ?

Answer (score 6):

You can also use es6 arrow notation if you have a compiler like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/)

`<Button onclick={() => this.props.setWizardState(1)}></Button>`

Answer (score 0):

Here's [a link](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html) at official reactjs website. Apparent you need bind this function instead of directly apply.

```
onClick={this.setWizardState.bind(this, 1)}
```